# Does X^2 divided to DF converge to F distribution when X^2 is Rao Scott chi squared statistic?

Tags: survey, asymptotics, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

I'm studying Rao-Scott chi-squared test, kind of survey sampling analysis method. It uses when we want to test independence between two variables under complex sampling data instead of Pearson chi-squared test. simply, R*C two way table.

As I see the paper (Thomas and Rao, 1987), the Rao-Scott statistic approximately converge to chi-squared distribution. But Thomas and Rao said that if Rao-Scott statistic(denoted X^2) divided into df(degree of freedom, (R-1)(C-1)), then it approximately converge to F distribution. But I have no idea how to induce this result. As I know, F statistic organize "(X1^2/v1)/(X2^2/v2) ~ F" when X1 and X2 are independent. **But the paper just said "approximately X^2/df ~ F". And there is no procedure about this conclusion.**

So I searched to solve this problem. I found this formula in wikipedia(chi-squred distribution - Relation to other distiribution; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) which is

[image]

**Is this relate to my problem? If not, How can I solve my problem?**
furthermore, **How can I get the paper which concluded that formula?** Please let me know either of them.

Thank you for your patient. English is not my first language. maybe reading is so hard. Thanks again!